# How to use JForm field in a editor-xtd plugin modal window

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, joomla3.0

I successfully converted my joomla 3 gallery module to a joomla 3 plugin and created an editor-xtd plugin witch opens the file settings.php in a modal window.

In the body tag of this window i would like to use the same xml Form field like in my manifest xml file of the module.

```
<form>
<fieldset name="catid" addfieldpath="/plugins/editors-xtd/gallery/fields/">
        <field
            name="gallery-category"
            type ="gallerycategory"
            label="Gallery cat id"
            description="Gallery cat id"
            default = "0"
        />
</fieldset>
```

Is there a way to get the xml form field rendered in the body of this php file?

Answer (score 0):

Over the weekend the I managed to load my own settings.xml file and render a select box in the php modal.

```
<?php

    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
    define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath( '..'.DS.'..'.DS.'..'.DS ) );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );


    $xmlPath = dirname(__FILE__) .'/forms/settings.xml';

    jimport('joomla.form.form');
    $form = JForm::getInstance('idform', $xmlPath);

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>titel</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../administrator/templates/isis/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function insertCatId() {
                var codeInsert = document.getElementById("settings_category").value;
                var tag = "{category:"+codeInsert+"}";
                window.parent.jInsertEditorText(tag, ' . json_encode($this->eName) . ');
                window.parent.jModalClose();
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
        <form name="idform">
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control-label">
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <label>Insert category id</label>
                </div>
                <div class="controls">
                    <?php echo $form->getInput('category', 'settings'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </fieldset>
        <button onclick="insertCatId();" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo JText::_('Insert'); ?></button>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This

```
<?php echo $form->getInput('category', 'settings'); ?>
```

renders a standard select box but not the typical Joomla input box with suggestion and autocomplete function. How do i achieve this?